# Pulling Facebook status with jQuery returning null

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

I am trying to pull the status updates from a Facebook Page. I have the url for the feed:
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=141941024749
Putting that into the browser returns the feed, however when I try to pull the same thing via ajax I get null. Here is the jQuery code I am using.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=141941024749",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Seems like it should be straight forward. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is the first thing everyone always tried to do with ajax, and it never works. Sadface. :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
You cannot cross-domain ajax.

**Long answer:**
You'll need to write a server-side script or application to proxy the request for you, then hit that as opposed to the actual feed.

Answer (score 2):

**Better Short answer:**
Use JSONP at their 'graph' API instead.

**Better Long answer:**
You do **not** have to use server-side at all.  You can simply do:

```
$.JSON("http://graph.facebook.com/[USERID]/feed?callback=?", function(response) {
    /* do something with response object here */
}
```

Works great, but, naturally, requires the target user to have their feed public.

Comment: This is great. I knew there had to be a way. I had just chalked it up to facebook not making it easy to get info out.